# Loading users from Active Directory into a Rails 3.1 Active Record database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ldap, netldap

**Update 11/30/11** 
I made some changes in the code snippet where I found errors. I am now successfully authenticating for sure, but am getting this error after attempting the ldap.search call:

```
<OpenStruct code = 1, message="Operations Error">
```

Using Rails 3.1.0 and ruby 1.9.2 on Windows Server 2008 R2

**Original Message**
I'm brand new to Ruby, rails and programming. I have an application that will have to authenticate to our Active Directory server while maintaining a list of users separate from AD.

I'm attempting to use net-ldap to establish the connection, search AD and load the users, but I get 0 results with each attempt to run.

I've put this together based on samples I've seen, but when I customize it to my company, it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas/critiques are most welcome.

thanks!

I've set this as a method in my User class model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :name, :email, :team, :office, :points_attributes
  validates_presence_of :username, :name, :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email
  has_one :points
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :points

  def self.import_all
  # initialization stuff. set bind_dn, bind_pass, ldap_host, base_dn and filter

  ldap = Net::LDAP.new(:host => "dc.mycompany.com", :port => 389)
  if ldap.bind(:method => :simple, :username => "username@mycompany.com", :password => "secret")
  else
    p ldap.get_operation_result
  end

  begin
  # Build the list
  filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq("displayName", "J*")
  attrs = ["givenName", "sn", "physicalDeliveryOfficeName", "sAMAccountName"]
  records = new_records = 0
  ldap.search(:base => "DC=mycompany,DC=com", :attributes => attrs, :filter =>  filter,  :return_result => false) do |entry|
    name = entry.givenName.to_s.strip + " " + entry.sn.to_s.strip
    username = entry.sAMAccountName.to_s.strip
    email = entry.sAMAccountName.to_s.strip + "@mycompany.com"
    office = entry.physicalDeliveryOfficeName.to_s.strip
    user = User.find_or_initialize_by_username :name => name, :username => username, :email => email, :office => office
    if user.new_record?
      user.save
      Points.find_or_create_by_user_id(user.id)
      new_records = new_records + 1
    else
      user.touch
    end
    records = records + 1
  end
  p ldap.get_operation_result

    logger.info( "LDAP Import Complete: " + Time.now.to_s )
    logger.info( "Total Records Processed: " + records.to_s )
    logger.info( "New Records: " + new_records.to_s )

    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Which version of ruby-net-ldap are you using?

Comment: I'm using gem net-ldap 0.2.2 which is apparently different from ruby-net-ldap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error I'm getting is due to some of the attributes I'm searching for not existing on all the users under the tree I'm looking at.

Thanks to any that looked at this, but I believe I can move on to resolving how to handle entries without those attributes.